# MFMailComposeViewController won't dismiss on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6

In iOS 6 the presented `MFMailComposeViewController` will not dismiss if user attempts to send second email...

Everything works perfectly the first go around and email is sent. However, if email option is selected again the `MFMailComposeViewController` will not dismiss on cancel.

Here is how I implemented it:

```
- (IBAction)buttonEmailClick:(id)sender {
    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't send" message:@"This device is unable to send emails." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    NSDictionary *contactsInfo = [self contactsInfoFromPlistNamed:kConfigPlistName];
    [mailComposeViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[contactsInfo objectForKey:@"email"]]];
    //[mailComposeViewController setSubject:kEmailDefaultSubject];
    //[mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:text isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and then this:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = nil;
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sent" message:@"Your email was sent." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    }
    else if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"An error occured and your email was not sent." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    }

    [alert show];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It works fine in iOS 5 but not in iOS 6. I have tried replacing with non deprecated methods for iOS 6, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried creating a fresh MFMailComposeViewController each time they go to send an email? I'm not sure if you should be reusing it.

Comment: I think that is the problem! Are there methods to create a fresh MFMailComposeViewController once the email has been sent and the user is taken back to the presenting view controller? I really appreciate the quick response and help.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion would be to put `mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];` just before your call to `setToRecipients`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I will try that the second I get back to the Mac.

Comment: I think you're right. I wouldn't be surprised if Apple actually caches the mailComposeVC behind the scenes too. Subsequent loads are much faster than the first even when you alloc init again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController * composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
composer.delegate = self;
```

-(void)mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error: should be called if you assign that class to the delegate